# create JQuery object by passing DOM object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So, let say I have this:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.id = "whatever";`
```

So, `d` is the DOM object,

how can I create or convert it into jQuery  object?

e.g.
`$(d)` ???

and, how to 'read' all attributes of the jQuery object?  just like the var_dump of PHP.

Comment: If you just want to see the attributes and functions associated with $(d) do a console.log($(d)) which will print the details of the object $(d) in the firebug console. This will work only with firefox with firebug add on

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
// create a jQuery-boosted div
$div = $('<div></div>');
$div.attr('id','someId');
alert($div.attr('id'));

// to get the DOM element:
var div = $div[0];

// or
var div = $div.get(0);
```

or just wrap the dom element in `$()` as you suggested:

```
$(d).attr('id','someId');
$(d).blah();
```

Use [`attr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes) to get/set element attributes. I'm not sure if there's a one-liner that can dump all of an element's attributes and their respective values ([firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) serves that purpose for me), but you can create an array with all the attribute names you're interested in, and do something like:

```
var attr = ['name', 'id', 'src', 'foo'];
var len = attr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    alert($(d).attr(attr[i]));
```

or using [`$.each`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each):

```
$.each(['name', 'id', 'src', 'foo'], function(i,val) {
    alert( 'Attribute: ' + val + ' Value: ' + $(d).attr(val) );
});
```